# Improving large switch case

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

I have an API (built with spring boot) which has a method that provides a template file on format `.xlxs` delivered on a response DTO object with a base64 inside of it.

```
    @GetMapping("/getLoadTemplate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getLoadTemplate(@RequestParam(name = "type", defaultValue = "!") String type) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO;
        if (notInTypes(type))
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(badRequest("Tipo de archivo invalido."));
        try {
            responseDTO = loadQuotasService.getFileTemplate(type);
            return ResponseEntity.status(responseDTO.getStatus()).body(responseDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body(errorResponse(logger, e));
        }
    }
```

The request object is a simple string that can be on any of the types of the classes that have a xlxs template, so each class has it own LOAD_NAME value. Example `public final static String LOAD_NAME = "POLITICAS_AFILIADO"`

```
public static boolean notInTypes(String type){
        if(type == null) return true;
        String[] validTypes = {QuotaLoad.LOAD_NAME, QuotaModify.LOAD_NAME, QuotaState.LOAD_NAME,
                AffiliatePolitics.LOAD_NAME, AffiliateRisk.LOAD_NAME, BuyerEvaluation.LOAD_NAME,
                HabeasRegister.LOAD_NAME, QuotaBuyer.LOAD_NAME, ClintonList.LOAD_NAME, BuyerQualification.LOAD_NAME};
        return !Arrays.asList(validTypes).contains(type);
    }
```

**PROBLEM**
This is the service method ... It's filled of repetitive code and a super big switch block. Will be difficult to mantainf

```
public ResponseDTO getFileTemplate(String type) {
        ASRFile template = null;
        switch (type) {
            case QuotaLoad.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(QuotaLoad.TEMPLATE, QuotaLoad.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case QuotaModify.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(QuotaModify.TEMPLATE, QuotaModify.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case QuotaState.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(QuotaState.TEMPLATE, QuotaState.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case AffiliatePolitics.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(AffiliatePolitics.TEMPLATE,
                        AffiliatePolitics.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case AffiliateRisk.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(AffiliateRisk.TEMPLATE,
                        AffiliateRisk.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case BuyerEvaluation.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(BuyerEvaluation.TEMPLATE,
                        BuyerEvaluation.CATEGORY);
                break;
// more equal code ...
```

**How can I impprove this repetitive code?**

Comment: are things like `QuotaLoad.LOAD_NAME` just string constants? Are things like `QuotaLoad` beans or plain classes with a static field? Do they have a common interface? Would be useful if you would show an example how those look because spring injection can do a lot for you here

Comment: Related - https://refactoring.guru/smells/switch-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a Map (as I don't know the type of your category, I'll use TypeOfCategory instead):

```
private static final Map<String, TypeOfCategory> typeCategories = Map.of(
        QuotaLoad.TEMPLATE, QuotaLoad.CATEGORY,
        ... );
```

You can use this map to rewrite notInTypes but getFileTemplate will be reduced significantly:

```
public ResponseDTO getFileTemplate(String type) {
    if (typeCategories.containsKey(type)) {
         return fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(type, typeCategories.get(type));
    }
    return null; // or a dummy, or throw an exception...
}
```

Comment: The standard name for this refactoring is _Replace Conditional with Polymorphism_, and it is useful in all sorts of cases.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- (IMO) this isn't a real case of "with polymorphism" since there's no polymorphism involved. That would require you to already have an instance of something that represents the correct `type` with a methods that would return you the category and template. You could have a factory method with a big switch statement to make those objects :D

Comment: Wonderfull, this approach was simple and powerful.

Comment: @zapl I had misunderstood the original switch to be calling different strategies rather than using merely different arguments. (And I just finished writing an annotation processor to generate exactly those "type registration types" and load them via SPI, so I'm probably predisposed to see it everywhere...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring to autowire little objects for you that contain all the information without knowledge of them inside your service. For example define

```
public class FileInfo {
    public final String type;
    public final String template;
    public final String category;

    public FileInfo(String type, String template, String category) {
        this.type = type;
        this.template = template;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

And in each of your classes (`QuotaLoad`, ...) give spring an instance of that type.

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Component
    static class SomeClassInfo extends FileInfo {
        public SomeClassFileProvider() {
            super("TYPE_A", "abfcf134===", "CATEGORY_A");
        }
    }
}
```

Now use them in a Service like so

```
@Service
class MyService {
    private final Map<String, FileInfo> supportedTypes;

    // all of them are autowired here
    public MyService(List<FileInfo> fileInfos) {
        this.supportedTypes = fileInfos.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                it -> it.type,
                it -> it
            ));
    }

    public boolean isValidType(String type) {
        return supportedTypes.containsKey(type);
    }

    public String getTemplate(String type) {
        FileInfo info = supportedTypes.get(type);
        return info != null ? info.template : null;
    }

    public String getCategory(String type) {
        FileInfo info = supportedTypes.get(type);
        return info != null ? info.category : null;
    }

    // that would be the former big switch
    public ResponseDTO getFileTemplate(String type) {
        FileInfo info = supportedTypes.get(type);
        if (info == null)
            return null;
        return fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(info.template, info.category);
    }
}
```

If your classes already are spring beans, you can also just autowire them and enforce the required fields in them by letting them implement a common interface.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `Map<String, FileProvider> providers;`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no, the way `Collectors.toMap` is used maps `FileProvider` to essentially `Map<type, fileKey>`. You could do that if you want to keep a reference to the provider class around by doing `toMap(it -> it.type, it -> it)`

Comment: Nvm, I was confused that the question was using some unique class rather than `fileRepository` between each case.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've changed to code a bit to make it less confusing and more fitting to the question at hand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your 2 service methods in the following way, so that in the end you can remove completely the method `boolean notInTypes(String type)`, which has duplicate references of the static code that you use in the other service method `getFileTemplate(String type)`.

```
        @GetMapping("/getLoadTemplate")
        public ResponseEntity<?> getLoadTemplate(@RequestParam(name = "type", defaultValue = "!") String type) {
         
            try {
                ResponseDTO responseDTO = loadQuotasService.getFileTemplate(type);
                return responseDTO != null ? ResponseEntity.status(responseDTO.getStatus()).body(responseDTO) : ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(badRequest("Tipo de archivo invalido."))
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body(errorResponse(logger, e));
            }
        }
```

Then you would have

```
public ResponseDTO getFileTemplate(String type) {
     
        //Switch will break if passed argument is null!
        if (type == null) {
           return null;
        }
        ASRFile template = null;
        switch (type) {
            case QuotaLoad.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(QuotaLoad.TEMPLATE, QuotaLoad.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case QuotaModify.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(QuotaModify.TEMPLATE, QuotaModify.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case QuotaState.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(QuotaState.TEMPLATE, QuotaState.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case AffiliatePolitics.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(AffiliatePolitics.TEMPLATE,
                        AffiliatePolitics.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case AffiliateRisk.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(AffiliateRisk.TEMPLATE,
                        AffiliateRisk.CATEGORY);
                break;
            case BuyerEvaluation.LOAD_NAME:
                template = fileRepository.findByFileOriginalNameAndCategory(BuyerEvaluation.TEMPLATE,
                        BuyerEvaluation.CATEGORY);
                break;
             default:
             return null;  // <---------- If type is not matched in switch then it is not a valid type
     }
```

Comment: Pretty well I'll take that one but still having a lot of cases.. inside ¿Hot to improve that?